# Limit if series is conditionally convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is conditionally convergent and $a_n \ne 0 \forall n$, determine with justification $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n|$, assuming the limit exists.

Actually, I dont know if it is possible to find the exact limit, but because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is conditionally convergent that means $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. So by the ratio test,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n| < 1$

But this isnt the answer they are probably looking for?

Answer (score 4):

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$$ the series is absolutely convergent! 
But your series isn't.

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| > 1$$ the series diverges, but your series doesn't.

So it must hold $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = 1$$ by exclusion.

Comment: But the ratio test is applied to ANY series? Not just absolute convergent series

Comment: You can apply the ratio test to any series IF the limit exists. Then you definitely know stuff if it's strict smaller then 1 (absolutely convergent) or strict greater then 1 (it diverges) . If it equals one it's undecidable. So series which are convergent but not absolutelly must have a limit equal to 1 (IF the limit exists!).